# Как правильно написать Description и Title для двуязычного сайта для корректного отображения в Гугле

Tags: php, google-search

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы google правильно определял язык страницы? Сайт на двух языках: фр и англ. Во фр гугле выдается title и description на англ. В поиске Google правильно дает ссылку на фр страницу, но (!) title и description отображает с английской версии. Сайт на PHP с MySQL.

Пример: ищу сайт в гугле на фр, гугл показывает результат с ссылкой на фр страницу, но с описанием на англ. Нажимаю на ссылку, переход на фр страницу, смотрю код, Description и Title на французском, как и должно быть, но гугл показывает их на англ!

Смотрел рекомендации Google, сделал как гугл рекомендует.

- теги link rel hreflang есть и на фр и на англ версиях страниц.
  HTML:
- Тег lang есть на страницах
  HTML:
- SiteMap.xml добавлен в Google Search Console с тегами
  HTML:

В начале страницы php, присваиваем значение переменным в зависимости от языка: en или fr:
PHP:

```
if($_SESSION["lang"] == "en") {
        $atitleMf = "Заголовок на англ";
        $adescription = "Описание на англ.";
    } else {
        $atitleMf = "Заголовок на фр";
        $adescription = "Описание на англ.";
    }
```

В теге head:

```
<title><?= $atitleMf; ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?= $adescription; ?>">
```

Есть подозрение, что Гуглу что-то не нравится в том, как присваивается значение description и title..

Правильно ли это? Как можно сделать, чтобы гугл отображал title и description корректно? на англ для англ гугла, на фр для фр гугла.

Comment: можно ссылки на французскую и английскую версии? полагаю google считает обе версии одним сайтом. [тут](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly) можно вставить ссылку своего сайта и посмотреть как его видит робот. вставьте поочередно обе ваши версии и посмотрите.

Answer (score 0):

Google - это робот. Используйте не сессии, а заголовок `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` для определения языка.

Когда робот заходит на вашу страницу, то он видит только версию по умолчанию.

Comment: Какая будет разница для гугла $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] и сессией? Гуглу не все равно, что написано на php? я так понимаю, что он индексурует страницы на html, и чтобы проиндексировать их у него есть SiteMap, ведь URL для фр и англ версии разные..